# Page redirecting when clicking on blank space on angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular7, angular-routing

I want to redirect to another page when I get some response from the server. (This process is too slow, and take almost 60 seconds to get the response from server). Meanwhile, I will show some spinner kind of thing, And when I get the response, I will redirect to another page. Looks simple?

Yes, But the problem is, **Page is not getting redirected automatically when I get the response. It stays on the same page, Now, If I click anywhere on the page, It redirected to another page, Little weird situation.**

```
this.optimizationService
      .runOptimization(this.runOptimizationModel)
      .subscribe(optimizationResult => {  // this is the first service which send request to server.

        this.optimizationService.notificationEvent.subscribe(eventData => {
          console.log(eventData); // this is another external service for notifications in which, when I will get the response, I want to redirect to another page. 
          if (eventData && eventData.length) {
            this._router.navigate([this.optimizationResultScreenURL, 'e1517589-905e-485b-b7ee-7bc6521dcc93']); // This is url rerouting. If I cut and paste this line after first service subscription, it is working fine. 
          }
        });
      });
```

**Is this situation, because, we are getting a response from the second service after 60 seconds. This is a little weird scenario, but it is happening. 
 Is this 60 second the *villain*.**

Comment: Is your `ChangeDetectionStrategy` set to `OnPush` by any chance?

Comment: No, it was not, I tried that also, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solve my issue finally.

> return this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['/path/to/route']));

Problem was, Router Navigate does not activate onInit after external request. The second subscription was using the external request for notification.

Reference: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20112#issuecomment-398060545

Answer (score 2):

Could you try something along these lines? (Multiple nested subscribes are not a good practice)

```
this.optimizationService
      .runOptimization(this.runOptimizationModel)
      .pipe(
            switchMap(optiResult => this.optimizationService.notificationEvent),
            filter(eventData => eventData && eventData.length),
            tap(eventData => this._router.navigate(/* extract URL data here */))
      )
      .subscribe();
```

I'm not entirely clear on what the first request does, or where you use its response, but the theory in my answer is to use RxJS operators to control the flow. Hope this is useful.

Comment: I've chosen `switchMap`, but other operators may do the trick, depending on whether you expect multiple requests. `switchMap` will make sure the previous request is unsubscribed if it is unfinished when new data arrives.

Comment: yeah, I tried, and it is still working same. When I am clicking anywhere on the page, it is redirecting, but not automatically.

Comment: Are you making this call in ngOnInit?

Comment: No, it is happening on a button click, When I will get the response, I want to redirect to another page.

Comment: There may be some issue where the click isn't considered "complete". Can you try putting the call in ngOnInit and see if that works? If so, I'd say there's an issue with the click event…